# Ordering objects in firebase Array in ngRepeat using elements stored at a different location in the database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to order the objects in my array in the ngRepeat using values stored in firebase under a different thread. See code and images. I am currently using the following code, it doesn't give errors but neither does it order my objects according the the amount of votes:

```
ng-repeat="for in For | orderBy: '-dataVotes[for.ref].total' | limitTo: 30"
```

This is where i get the dataVotes:

```
firebase.database().ref("votes").on('value', function(data) {
  dataVotes = data.val();
  $scope.dataVotes = dataVotes;
});
```

See the attached images of the firebase. This is where the votes of each topic is stored. Every ID is an element of an corresponding object in the array. I want to order the array according to the total field:

[image]

The objects in the array are created using this thread in the database. Notice how the ref us the same as the ID in the votes thread.:

[image]

So how can I order my objects in the array according to these votes (total)?

Comment: You should really accomplish this on the server: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a function. See code below:
In the HTML:

```
ng-repeat="for in For | orderBy: orderFunc | limitTo: 30"
```

In the Javascript:

```
$scope.orderFunc = function(element){
    order = -(dataVotes[element.ref].total) ;
    return order
}
```

My objects are sorted as wished.